# MySqli Query result row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want use one column value in mysqli query but I am not able to find way of use it. My query is like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tbl_settings");
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($row['automatic'] ==on){

    $number= "$result['automatic']";
    echo $number;
     $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT _quid FROM tbl_quotes where qu_status=0 ORDER BY _quid ASC LIMIT 5");
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

    $qu_time = getDatetimeNow();
    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tbl_quotes SET qu_status=1,qu_favorite=0, qu_time='$qu_time' where _quid=".$result['_quid']." ORDER BY _quid ASC");



    }
```

I want get value of column **automatic_number** and want use it as **LIMIT** like this

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT _quid FROM tbl_quotes where qu_status=0 ORDER BY _quid ASC LIMIT $number");
```

I am trying from half hour but not able to find way of it. Let me know if any expert can help me. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by *I want use one column value in mysqli query* ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be more specific.

Comment: Hi! @SushankPokharel  Please check my edited question. Thanks

Comment: Hi! @Ravi  Please check my edited question. Thanks

Comment: @MeenaParmar I still don't understand your question. what is your expected output ?

Comment: @Ravi sorry for it. I want use that number as next query limit which I have separate written.

Comment: Is it "automatic" or "automatic_number"? Change the select clause in your first query.

Comment: @JeroenHeier automatic and automatic_number is two different column in tbl_settings. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mistake

```
if($row['automatic'] ==on)
```

correct:
 `if($row['automatic'] =='on')`

if you want to assign value of `$result['automatic']` then

```
$number=$result['automatic'];
```

this may be he reason you are not getting limit

in here `$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT _quid FROM tbl_quotes where qu_status=0 ORDER BY _quid ASC LIMIT 6");`

Comment: I want use automatic_number value not value of automatic as limit. automatic_number and automatic is two different column in table tbl_settings. Thanks

Comment: have tried changing the if condition with my answer & what you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

query:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT _quid FROM tbl_quotes where qu_status=0 ORDER BY _quid ASC LIMIT " .$number;
```

execution:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use value the atomatic_number in the limit where the atomatic_number is the table of the tbl_settings then just change

```
$number=$result['automatic'];
```

to

```
$number=$result['automatic_number'];
```

then

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT _quid FROM tbl_quotes where qu_status=0 ORDER BY _quid ASC LIMIT $number");
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.